# Oauth with Angular and Node

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, oauth, cors

I am having trouble to get oauth working on angular.
when I enter the link directly to the browser

```
http://localhost:8080/auth/twiter
```

I am able to connect using oauth and get a respond
However when I try to do that in angular with the following code

```
    login_twitter : function login_twitter(){
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http.get('auth/twitter')
      .success(function (data,status){
        if(status === 200 && data.state=='success'){
          user = data.user.name;
          defered.resolve();
        }
        else{
          deferred.reject();
        }
      })
      .error(function (data){
        deferred.reject();
      });
    return deferred.promise;
```

I am getting an error from the browser

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load ....link... No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.
```

In my server I tried with (res.header  and res.setHeader)

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8080');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

    next();
});
```

Can any one please help me out? I've been stuck for a while.
Or is there any examples that can use Oauth to login with angular and node , because most of tutorials are with node and ejs/jade

Answer (score 1):

The Twitter auth strategy requires that the user be signed into Twitter and has allowed your "app" permission to access your Twitter account information. This cannot be done with a XHR because how would the user enter their Twitter credentials to log into Twitter if the user wasn't already signed in? How would the user approve the permissions your Twitter "app" is requesting if the request is sent via XHR?

This applies to all of the Passport strategies that utilize OAuth or OpenID. The user's browser has to go directly to the auth provider's site so that they can either A) login to the auth provider or B) approve the permissions you're requesting in your application. Once the user has done that the auth provider (in your case Twitter) will then redirect the user's browser back to your application's endpoint with some kind of token which your application will then use to request information from the auth provider (such as email address, full name, etc.)

Comment: thanks, I was able to get a respond by directly entering the link http://localhost:8080/auth/twiter. However, the return type is an object {status, user}, and it printed out on the front-end of the page. Is there any way that I can read of from the object? I am try to read the object then reidrect to other pages in the angular side

Comment: @user3423482 you'll have to change your server side application to store that information in the user's session and then redirect back to the page where your angular application exists. On that page you'll either want to put the information from the user's session directly into a top-level JavaScript object and have angular read from it or have your angular application make an ajax request to your server to get the user's session data.